# UTF8 encode script not encoding uppercase diacritic letters correctly

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization, encode

I have a webpage that is pulling in data from 2 different sources, one is UTF8 encoded in the database (source A), and the other is not encoded (source B). Both sources contain various languages, and therefore include some foreign letters.

I have UTF8 decoding at the top of the page;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Which I have found means I need to encode the data being pulled from source B, in order for it to display correctly on the page. It all seemed to be working fine until I noticed an uppercase Ö was displaying as ??. I have now done some testing and found that most (if not all) uppercase diacritics display ?? instead of the correct character. Lowercase letters (ö, ô etc) all seem to work fine. I have tried editing the source as well as writing the correct UTF8 encoded characters to the page and narrowed it down to the encoding being incorrect, rather than the decoding on the actual page.

The javascript UTF8 encode function I am using is as follows;

```
string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
    var utftext = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
        if (c < 128) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
        }
        else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }
        else {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }
    }
     return utftext;
```

I am not too clued up on Javascript, so I am ashamed to say that a lot of this goes over my head. Can anyone help me to update the encode function so it will also correctly encode the uppercase diacritic letters, or is it not as straightforward as that?

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. You do not need to do any UTF8 en/decoding if the stored text is already in UTF8 - make sure it is and you can drop the scripts. Re-save source B in UTF8 and your problems are gone

Comment: @mplungjan unfortunately I cannot control the encoding of Source B, it comes from the client database.

Comment: Then you need to know what encoding the client database is using and transcode the values to UTF-8.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts There is no encoding on the client database, letters in their database table display as Ô etc when viewed in SQL.
I have this issue even if I pass in a hardcoded string containing a mixture of uppercase and lowercase diacritics. So if I were to use the function in the OP and put 'utf8Encode('â, ê, î, ô, û, Â, Ê, Î, Ô, Û')' into the page code then I would get the output 'â, ê, î, ô, û, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??'

Comment: It is not possible to have 'No encoding'. The character values have to be represented in some manner.

Comment: @dragonthoughts Ok, apologies. What I mean is that when I look at the data in SQL it is represented as öÖ êÊ etc, without any obvious encoding. The data from Source B is treated the same as if I hardcode some diacritic characters to the page, I.e. I just get ?? for all diacritic capital letters. Lowercase encode/decode fine.

Comment: That is because you are double encoding. You are treating UTF8 code points as something else, then trying to encode those bytes into UTF8.

Comment: @dragonthoughts thank you. Can you explain what I can do to fix it? And also why it encodes/decodes correctly for (for instance) a lowercase ö but not uppercase Ö?

Comment: As I said before, your first step is to find what encoding the strings are returned to you as. Then you can look at how to transcode them.

Comment: I’m sorry if I’m asking stupid questions, but if we were to forget the database input and pretend the text was all hard coded, then why would the page still struggle with uppercase diacritics? So, referring to my previous comment; “I have this issue even if I pass in a hardcoded string containing a mixture of uppercase and lowercase diacritics. So if I were to use the function in the OP and put 'utf8Encode('â, ê, î, ô, û, Â, Ê, Î, Ô, Û')' into the page code then I would get the output 'â, ê, î, ô, û, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??'”

Comment: Character encoding is the byte representation of the character.
A String is a sequence of characters.
Internally, the string's contents will be held by whatever encoding JavaScript uses.
What I think you are attempting to do, is to treat the input as a stream of bytes and convert it to a string.
Since your input is a string, it is already a sequence of characters. You cannot change the string's encoding.
If your algorthim took in a sequence of codepoints it could in principle return an array or stream of bytes representing those codepoints in UTF-8.

Comment: You may find this helpful to start understanding character encodings: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding and https://www.w3.org/International/articles/definitions-characters/

Comment: In short, your function only corrupts your strings. If the data comes in as a string then output as a string and make sure that your web server actually serves the page as UTF-8, please.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help and patience with me @Dragonthoughts ! I think I am finally getting it now.

Comment: You are welcome. I should have mentioned that I'm a contributor to the articles that I referenced.